# Question about normal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ be a normal matrix. Prove that $Ax=0$ if and only if $A^*x=0$

and the star is for complex conjugate.

I am not sure how I would do this one the definition of normal matrix is $AA^{*}=A^{*}A$

But how would I start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Let's try the following:

$$\left\|A^*x\right\|^2=\langle A^*x,A^*x\rangle=\langle x, AA^*x\rangle=\langle x,A^*Ax\rangle=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle=\left\|Ax\right\|^2=0$$

Complete and fill in details

Comment: But how is $<A^{*}X,A^{*}X>=<x,AA^{*}x>$

Comment: @FernandoMartinez It's a very basic property of operators and inner product! $$\langle Tx,y\rangle=\langle x,T^*y\rangle$$ You **must know this** if you're dealing with normal matrices and etc.

Comment: Ok I did not know about that property. So then if both their norm are equal to zero then that that means then both Ax=0 and $A^{*}x=0$ so then the proof is complete I think

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Yes, that's right.